# Prove that for all $n,m,M \in\mathbb N$, there exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $ (m+k\cdot n)>M$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove this using the Well Ordering of Natural Numbers,

So supposing that there exists a smallest element, $j$ for the set of $M$ where $(m + kn) > j$...

I don't know what I'm doing already. I know I need to prove that there exists some $k$ that will make $(m +kn) > M$, but how?

$(m + k \cdot n) > M$

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the notation in the title means.

Comment: Many students, when they are learning about proofs and notation, will try to fill the proofs with complicated notation and a minimum of language. This is generally a practice that's better to avoid - it's perfectly all right to be wordy, if it improves the clarity.

Comment: Are you using the set of positive integers as the definition of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: If zero is included the statement is not true, so it must be.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L=\{M\in \mathbb{N}|$ The statement is not true for $M\}$. We assume the set is non-empty, and by the well ordering principle, the set has a least element, say $J$. If $J>1$ Then $m+k*n>J-1$ (Since J-1 is a natural number) for some $n$, $k$ and $m$, so since $n\ge 1$, $m+(k+1)*n\ge m+k*n+1>J$, so that $J\notin L$, a contradiction, so $J-1$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$ and $J=1$, but the inequality is true for any $m$, $k$ and $n$, so we reach a contradiction, and $J$ is empty, and that is what you wanted to show.

Comment: @vadim123 Yeah sorry, I kinda forgot that while answering. I fixed it!